# INSERT dynamic set of rows into table after generating new primary key

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure that essentially 'shares' a playlist with another user. It takes a table row, creates a new primary key, and `INSERTS` a new row with the new primary key into the table. Then data in a linked second table is duplicated with the new primary key inserted.

At a high level, I want to create a new playlist with the same tracks (`playlist_msg`), but generate a new `playlist_id` for a new user and associate the same tracks with the new `playlist_id`.

My tables are structured as follows:

playlist_tbl

```
playlist_id varchar(30) - Primary key
user_id int
description varchar(300)
created_dt datetime
```

playlist_msg_tbl

```
playlist_id varchar(30) - Primary key
sequence int - Primary key - basically the track number for the playlist
msg_id varchar(30)
```

So the idea is that when the playlist is shared, inside the stored procedure code, a new `playlist_id` is generated and a new `user_id` assigned in `playlist_tbl`. Then in `playlist_msg_tbl`, a duplicate `msg_id` associated with the old `playlist_id` is `INSERTED` into `playlist_msg_tbl` with the new `playlist_id`.

My problem is that because the number of rows in `playlist_msg_tbl` will be different, I need to figure out how to write some sort of a loop that does an `INSERT` for each row in `playlist_msg_tbl` dynamically.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Share]
    @description varchar(300),
    @recipientId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @newPlaylistId varchar(30)

    exec dbo.GenerateString 1, 1, 1, null, 30, @newPlaylistId OUT

    INSERT INTO playlist (playlist_id, user_id, description, created_dt)
    VALUES (@newPlaylistId, @recipientId, @description, GETDATE())

    --This is where my theoretical loop would go, not sure how to handle the code for that
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to why exactly you need a loop...

Wouldn't an `INSERT` just work?

```
INSERT INTO playlist_msg_tbl (playlist_id, sequence, msg_id) 
    SELECT 
        @newPlayListId, x.sequence, x.msg_id 
    FROM 
        playlist_msg_tbl 
    WHERE 
        playlist_id = @oldPlaylistId
```

Comment: SQL isn't my strongest language, so I wasn't sure if a loop was needed or not. By the looks of your answer, I'm speculating that this will insert every row where the playlist_id equals the old playlist id, correct? If so, that is the answer I'm looking for.